# How to style two buttons with in one div

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible style buttons in one div?

I want to style buttons when clear buttons appear on the backend.

When the second button disappears the first button should be `width: 100%;`. Any solution? And I tried `button ~ button` and its only works in `last-child`.

Please check the snippet

```css
.container button + button:first-child {
   width: 60%;
   float: left;
}
.container button + button:last-child {
   width: 40%;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button>Visit</button>
   <button>Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you make the first button disappear?

Comment: First button don't disappear. Just second one

Comment: Whatever. **How** does the button in question disappear? JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container button:first-child {
  width: 40%;
}

.container button:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Visit</button>
  <button>Clear</button>
</div>
```